# Wordpress filter post between dates

Tags: html, css, wordpress

So I have created a category in wordpress where I post some events. I have created two custom field where I insert two dates ( duration of the event ). Now my client wants to have 3 sort options ( current, upcoming, past ) that should be present in a dropdown menu.

For that i have managed to create this:

```
        if($_ISSET('sort') && $_GET['sort'] == 'upcoming') {
            $args = array(
                'post_type'  => 'post',
                'meta_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'key' => 'm77_datefrom',
                        'value'   => date('Y-m-d'),
                        'compare'   => '>'
                    ),
                ),
            );
        }
        else if($_ISSET('sort') && $_GET['sort'] == 'past'){
            $args = array(
                'post_type'  => 'post',
                'meta_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'key' => 'm77_datefrom',
                        'value'   => date('Y-m-d'),
                        'compare'   => '<'
                    ),
                ),
            );
        }
```

The problem is that I cannot insert the "sort" parameter.
Url structure : domain.com/category/events

Any ideas how can i solve this problem ? Or is there a better way to do this ?